# How to upgrade extjs 3.4 project in 5

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I want to upgrade extjs 3.4 project in 5 what are the step i would follow.I have a view port which have multiple items, items has grid ,from, etc .

Comment: I agree the OP's question is too broad. But since Sencha released a new version and developers are thinking of upgrades, this question will ponder many

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot upgrade an extjs 3.4 project to extjs 5 by just changing the  files. ExtJS 3.4 is quiet old and the APIs are different. The 3.4 version don't even have concepts of MVC application and many of the advanced features. So, no matter how big or small your application is .. it is better to do a rewrite of your application using the MVC methodologies to make the application more maintainable and better equipped for the future.